# Subrect drawing to texture FBO within OpenGL ES Fragment Shader

Tags: opengl-es, fbo

I'm trying to draw to a subrect of a texture based FBO, but am having difficulty.  The FBO has dimensions of say 500x500 and I am trying to have the fragment shader only redraw say a 20x20 pixel subrect.  Modiyfing the full texture works without difficulty.

At first I tried setting glViewport to the needed subrect, but it doesn't look to be that simple.  I'm suspecting that the Vertex attributes affecting gl_Position and the varying texture coordinates are involved, but I can't figure out how.

Comment: What is your problem and what kind of result do you get? Just a shot in the dark: You are not clearing the buffer (glClear) are you?

Answer (score 0):

Turns out that I was trying to modify the texture coordinate attributes, but was more easily able to just modify the viewport using glViewport and gl_FlagCoord within the shader.